# How to add css file to the pdf document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I am trying to add a border to the header of the PDF document using css. But the border which I'm using in css is not taking to the pdf. Even for image also I'm using css only, it is taking, but for border it is not taking. Can you please help me to fix this border?

This is what I want http://imgset.net/WPHuNd

This is what I'm getting   http://imgset.net/VWUM5z

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ITPortal.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/oneHarmanMain.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/corev4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ITServiceCatalog.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ITPortal.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/compatibility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/IE9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/printContent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/downloadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/typearray.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" />
<style>
 #new-logo { 
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 124px;
   height: 66px;
 }
@media print {
 #new-logo { 
   visibility: visible;
   width: 124px;
   height: 66px;
 }
 input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
  text-align: center !important;
 }
 .title, .thead.item {
  margin-right: 1000px !important;
  position:fixed !important;
 }
 #Phead { border: 2px solid #000 !important; }
}
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    { 
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'mainContentWide', 'height=700,width=1300');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>'); 
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
 
 function update() { 
  var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {  
   if(i==0 || i == table.rows.length-1 || row.cells.length < 2 || row.className == "item category"){}else{ 
    var quantity=row.cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
    row.cells[1].innerHTML = quantity;
    var priceOne = row.cells[4].childNodes[0].value;
    row.cells[4].innerHTML = priceOne;
    var priceTwo = row.cells[5].childNodes[0].value;
    row.cells[5].innerHTML = priceTwo;
    var priceThree = row.cells[6].childNodes[0].value;
    row.cells[6].innerHTML = priceThree;
   }  
  }
  var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
  document.getElementById('grandTotal').innerHTML = total;

 }

</script>
<body>
 <div id="mainContentWide">
  <h2>WorkPlace Services</h2>
    <h3 class="curveBoxWide">Description</h3>
   
 <div id="new-logo"> <img src="image/back-logo.png" alt="Harman Logo"/></div>
 
  <table id="mytab1">
  <thead>
   <tr class="thead item" id="Phead">
    <th><span class="colm1">Desktop Software</span></th>
    <th><span class="colm1">Quantity</span></th>
    <th><span class="colm1">One time Price ($)</span</th>
    <th><span class="colm1">Annual Price ($)</span</th>
    <th><span class="colm1">One time Extended Cost ($)</span</th>
    <th><span class="colm1">Annual Extended Cost ($)</span</th>
    <th><span class="colm1">Sub-Total</span</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="item odd" class="test">
    <td class="title"><p>Symantec SEP</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">136</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Citrix</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">368</td>
    <td>85</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <td class="title"><p>Total:</p></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="grandTotal"><input id="total" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
  <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
  
  <button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML()" type="button" id="buttonPDF">Save as PDF</button> 
  <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="javascript:PrintElem('#mainContentWide')" style="margin: 0 20px; padding: 1px 30px" />
  <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 15px"> ('Save as PDF' is working on IE9 and above, chrome and Firefox browsers )</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my js file:

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
   Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data){   
   var mywindow = window.open('', 'mainContentWide', 'height=700,width=1300');
   mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>'); 
   mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>');
   mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
   mywindow.document.write(data);
   mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

   mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
   mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

   mywindow.print();
   mywindow.close();

   return true;
}  

function demoFromHTML() { 
    var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {    
            if(i==0 || i == table.rows.length-1 || row.cells.length < 2 || row.className == "item category"){}else{ 
                var quantity=row.cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
                row.cells[1].innerHTML = quantity;
                var priceOne = row.cells[4].childNodes[0].value;
                row.cells[4].innerHTML = priceOne;
                var priceTwo = row.cells[5].childNodes[0].value;
                row.cells[5].innerHTML = priceTwo;
                var priceThree = row.cells[6].childNodes[0].value;
                row.cells[6].innerHTML = priceThree;
            }  
        }
        var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
        document.getElementById('grandTotal').innerHTML = total;

    var pdf = new jsPDF('1', 'mm', [380, 350])

    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    , source = $('#mainContentWide')[0]

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    , specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    }

    margins = {
      top: 10,
      bottom: 10,
      left: 10,
      width:1000,
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
        source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        , margins.left // x coord
        , margins.top // y coord
        , {
            'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
            , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },
        function (dispose){alert('dispose');
          pdf.save('Software.pdf');
        },

        margins
    )  

    document.getElementById("buttonPDF").disabled = 'true'; 
}
```

CSS File:

```
@media print { 
    .title, .thead.item {
        margin-right: 1000px !important;
        position:fixed !important;
    }
    #Phead { border: 2px solid #000 !important; }
    #new-logo { 
        background-image: url("image/back-logo.png");
        width: 124px;
        height: 66px;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can drastically improve your JS file (simplify it) with the power of jQuery. You are already loading the library, so why not use it?

Comment: Ya, im having css file, but that is not working...

Comment: in css i added the border, but not taking to the pdf...

Comment: jsPDF table formatting is embedded into the code - you cannot change it based on your CSS.

Comment: :(   Is there any other plugin or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `border-collapse: collapse;` on the parent `<table>`.  Per [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#separated-borders), rows cannot have borders unless this property is set.  In most cases, the property default is `border-collapse: separate;` so it should just be a matter of overriding this.